# Can not load subscription packages of my app on Mac OS

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am using using Flutter's [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package. I am getting all the subscription packages in `notFoundIDs`. Works fine on the iOS
& Android